# objects of view controller hide behind of video background in swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, viewcontroller

i want create a login page for my app, in this case i want to use a video for background of login page, like vine,spotify,uber,...
i play video without problem and add some button and lable in storyboard to my view controller، after run app i can not see objects of view controller
i just see video and objects hide behind of video background how can fix this problem,,, 
thanks for helping

this is my code for playing video,,,

```
 lazy var playerLayer:AVPlayerLayer = {

    let player = AVPlayer(URL:  NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("BWWalkthrough", ofType: "mp4")!))
    player.muted = true
    player.allowsExternalPlayback = false
    player.appliesMediaSelectionCriteriaAutomatically = false
    var error:NSError?

    // This is needed so it would not cut off users audio (if listening to music etc.
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
    } catch var error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    }

    var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
    playerLayer.videoGravity = "AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill"
    playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    player.play()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"playerDidReachEnd", name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object:nil)
    return playerLayer
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
}
func playerDidReachEnd(){
    self.playerLayer.player!.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    self.playerLayer.player!.play()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your `playerLayer` below all the views created when your storyboard loads. Replacing

```
self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer)
```

with

```
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(self.playerLayer, atIndex:0)
```

should do the job, unless there are any subviews of the view controller view that you actually want to be behind the video layer.